# Making and using hotkeys in a DLL GTA SA

Tags: c++, dll

I made a little DLL in C++ that I inject into the GTA San Andreas game. Now I want to create hotkeys that work in-game. Like when I press F10 it sets the player's health to maximum. I already know how to set the health and all but I don't know how to make hotkeys.
Here is some code I found but it isn't for DLL usage I suppose:

```
bool customKeyHook(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg ,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(wParam)
    {
    case VK_F10:
        *playerHP = 200;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you found the solution? Is there any source where I can learn all this? I wanna reserve my < > keys to make the game slow and fast (speed it up ,  slow it down)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Thread with CreateThread an then create an infinite loop and wait for the keypress:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F10) & 1)
{

}
```